# Proving that a point on elliptic curve is smaller than half of group's order

Tags: elliptic-curves

Let's say I have an elliptic curve where generator $G_1$ has prime order $q$. Let's also say I have committed to a point $A_1 = a \cdot G_1$. Could I use the scheme below to prove that $a < \frac{q}{2}$?

---

Suppose the order of the curve is $2q$ (the order is even) and there is another generator $G_2$ such that $G_1 = 2 \cdot G_2$. The order of the group for this generator is then the same as the order of the curve ($2q$). To prove that $a < \frac{q}{2}$:

1. I compute $A_2 = (4a - 1) \cdot G_2$ and send it to the verifier.
2. The verifier can then check whether $\frac{A_2+G_2}{2} = A_1$, and if so, accept my proof.

The thinking is that points generated by $G_1$ are equal to points generated by $G_2$ only for even multiples of $G_2$. So, unless $A_2+G_2$ is even, it won't match a point in $G_1$. And then, the checking equation becomes:

$$
\frac{(4a - 1) \cdot G_2 + G_2}{2} = 2a \cdot G_2 = a \cdot G_1
$$

I don't think I need to worry about overflow here since the division should take care of that.

---

The biggest thing I'm not sure about is how division by 2 would work on an elliptic curve of even order:

- What would happen if we try to compute $\frac{3 \cdot G_2}{2}$ - would the result be undefined?
- What would happen if we try to divide a "negative" point by 2? For example: $\frac{-2 \cdot G_2}{2} = -1 \cdot G_2$ and at the same time $\frac{-2 \cdot G_2}{2} = \frac{(2q-2) \cdot G_2}{2} = (q - 1) \cdot G_2$. But $q - 1 \neq -1 \bmod 2q$.

I must be missing something here.

Comment: Why the order of $G_2$ is $2q$. With this you can find an order greater then the group order. It should be $q/2$?

Comment: Also, are you sure that generators as $G_2$ actually exist? I have never heard of anything like that but that could be just my lack of knowledge. Why not use an existing range-proof on $A$?

Comment: OP probably means that the curve's order is (a multiple of) $2q$ and that $G_2$ has order $2q$. In this case $G_1 = 2\cdot G_2$ does indeed have order $q$.

Comment: @fkraiem - indeed, that's what I've meant. I've updated the question to make this more clear.

Comment: @VincBreaker - range proofs would work, but they are pretty large and expensive. If this approach works, it is much more efficient than a typical range proof.

Comment: The thing that is confusing you is that, for $xG_2$ ($x$ even), there are two solutions to the point halving problem, $(x/2)G_2$ and $(x/2 + q)G_2$.  Which one you get would depend on the exact algorithm you use to compute point halving (unless your algorithm returns both)

Comment: @poncho - ah, I see. I'll create a separate question about point halving since this seems to be the source of my confusion.